# Perl - how to put escape sequence into string?

Tags: regex, perl

I am converting one form of regex to Perl-compatible regex. I need to replace all occurrences of `%s` to `\s`, so I am doing:

```
$s =~ s/(?<!%)%s/\s/g;
```

But it gives me error: `Unrecognized escape \s passed through at ....`. Actually I am understanding where the problem is, so probably I can’t convert to string some unknown escape sequence. But how do I bypass this thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to escape the \, like:

```
$s =~ s/(?<!%)%s/\\s/g;
```

For example

```
my $s = "this is a %s test with two %s sequences, the last one here %%s not changed";
$s =~ s/(?<!%)%s/\\s/g;
print "$s\n";
```

prints

```
this is a \s test with two \s sequences, the last one here %%s not changed
```

(not sure if you need the %%s to end up being just %s, if so it needs a little tweak or a second regexp to do that).

Comment: This was my first version, but i think, it is bad, cause i need later use that replaced string like perl RE pattern and it will contains \\s instead od \s and then i can't use it for replacing whitespaces.